# Auth0 sign-out of all applications

Tags: c#, auth0

I'm trying to call this endpoint `/v2/logout` to logout the user from the application. But it's not working.
Full endpoint: GET `https://{domain}/v2/logout?client_id={client_id}returnTo=LOGOUT_URL`
How can I log out a user from all other applications using Auth0. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the parameters and it'll log you out of all applications

Comment: @MattRaible I tried just https://{domain}/v2/logout and it doesn't logout at all.

Comment: @MattRaible It only logs out one application. Other applications were not logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 uses authentication with JWT:s. A JWT is like a passport proving your identity. The JWT is signed (but not encrypted), that means that any backend service that has access to the public part of the signing key can validate that the JWT is valid and not tempered with. It will only validate the JWT using the signing key, it will not make any request to Auth0 to check that the JWT is valid. (There are no sessions as such, if you would like to compare with session based user validation.)

Once an application obtained the JWT, you can only ask it kindly to delete it, you cannot enforce it and you can not make the JWT invalid. The SDK:s of Auth0 has such methods.

**What you can do** is to set a short expiry time on the JWT, typically minutes or at most hours. Then you use a Refresh Token for the client to use in order to obtain a new JWT (Access Token) **from Auth**